# Delphi property getter function using generics

Tags: delphi, generics, properties, delphi-xe2

It would be nice to have generic property getters/setters to perform a common task on each access.

That code gives a compile-time error in Delphi XE2 'E2008 Incompatible types'. A similar code gave an internal error during compilation, but never compiles. Do I make a mistake or it is a compiler limitation?

```
type TFoo = class
private
  function Get<T>: T;
public
  property Bar: Integer read Get<Integer>;
end;

function TFoo.Get<T>: T;
begin
  Result := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Btw, the implementation of generics was riddled with bugs in XE2. If you want to make use of generics, it would be very wise to update to a more modern version of Delphi with fewer generics bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following things can be generic in the Delphi language:

- classes, e.g. `TFooClass<T> = class`
- records, e.g. `TFooRecord<T> = record`
- interfaces, e.g. `TFooInterface<T> = interface`
- procedural types, e.g. `TFooProc<T> = procedure`
- methods, e.g. `procedure FooMethod<T>()`

Properties cannot be generic themselves, and cannot be implemented using generic getter or setter methods.